# Virtual Game Controller Driver

Tags: c++, virtual, device, device-driver, accelerometer

Is there any way that I can map a virtual game controller like ppjoy with c++? I will be receiving orientation data from a phone, and I want to use this as x and y axes. I don't need anything advanced, I just want maximum compatibility on windows.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a dll that lets me control ppjoy so I'm going to use that.

Comment: can you give the dll address please?

Comment: Hey nebkat can you please give me the link to that dll file as I am also working on a similar project